# Removing space in view attribute in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng repeat directive in which I set the height dynamically

```
 <ul>
<li ng-repeat="val in values" height-dir >{{val.a}}</li>
</ul>

    app.directive('heightDir',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<li ng-repeat="val in values" style="height:{{val.b}}%" >{{val.a}}</li>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

    }
  };
});
$scope.values= [{a:"Doe",b:10},{a:"bom",b:20},{a:"kal",b:30},{a:"jijo",b:40}];
```

the problem is when I run, there is a gap between the value and % so the style is not applied.How to solve this,anything I am missing? thank you.

Comment: Your posted code seems to be wrong. You have one `li` in directive and another one in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to wrong HTML markup being generated.

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul style="height:500px">
        <height-dir ng-repeat="val in values"></height-dir>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('heightDir',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<li style="height:{{val.b}}%" >{{val.a}}</li>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    }
  };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.values= [{a:"Doe",b:10},{a:"bom",b:20},{a:"kal",b:30},{a:"jijo",b:40}];
}
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12044/

Comment: It works fine I copied my code and cr4eated a plunker it works fine, but how wrong HTML mark up is generated http://plnkr.co/edit/odOer9FbjVWtYUc66ZKf?p=preview